# must be str not Cell

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I was writing some overly complicated code (it's my homework) and i ran into a type error i had never seen before. I've tried tweaking things but i honestly don't know how to solve this particular problem because i've never even heard of a type called Cell in Python.

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    hucre_1 = sayfa.cell(row = i, column = 1)
    hucre_1.value = students[i]
    hucre_0 = sayfa.cell(row = i, column = 3)
    hucre_0.value = random.randint(70, 100)
    if hucre_0.value >= 85:
        hucre_2 = sayfa.cell(row = i, column = 5)
        hucre_2.value = "Takdir"
        qr = pyqrcode.create(students[i] + " " + str(hucre_0.value) + " " + str(hucre_2))
        baslık = students[i] + ".png"
        qr.png(baslık, scale = 3)
    else:
        hucre_2 = sayfa.cell(row = i, column = 5)
        hucre_2.value = "Teşekkür"
        qr = pyqrcode.create(students[i] + " " + str(hucre_0.value) + " " + (hucre_2))
        baslık = students[i] + ".png"
        qr.png(baslık, scale = 3)
```

it says the error is about the "qr = pyqrcode.create... " part

Comment: Whats the exact error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mehmet\Desktop\python\diploma hw\code.py", line 20, in <module>
    qr = pyqrcode.create(students[i] + " " + str(hucre_0.value) + " " + hucre_2)
TypeError: must be str, not Cell        I wonder if the Cell part is because im using openpyxl

Comment: Note that hucre_2 is apparently a sayfa.cell object and the first assignment to qr has `str(hucre_2)`, while the second just has `(hucre_2)`.  Probably you need to convert hucre_2 to a string in the second case.

Comment: after i did that i got a unicode error but after an easy fix, it's all sorted out now. thanks dennis